# MySQL how to deal with nulls passed into a case statement

Tags: mysql, case

I'm using a case statement with MySQL.

When `f.winner` field is NULL, it returns "Loss" instead of `f.method`. So it seems as though the MySQL case statement can't handle blanks and nulls like this.

```
(
    CASE f.winner
        WHEN :fighter_id THEN "Win"
        WHEN NULL OR "0" THEN f.method
        ELSE "Loss"
    END
) AS result,
```

Sometimes both `f.winner` and `f.method` are blank, and I just want the result to return as blank in those situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `IFNULL` function and remove the `NULL` from your `WHEN` clause:

```
(
    CASE IFNULL(f.winner, "0")
        WHEN :fighter_id THEN "Win"
        WHEN "0" THEN f.method
        ELSE "Loss"
    END
) AS result,
```

Comment: This worked. I did have to change it to `WHEN "0" OR "" THEN f.method` though because it was returning Loss for all blanks.